# DataGrip (Idea DB plugin) extremely slow fetching

Tags: sql, intellij-idea, datagrip, timesten

I am using IntelliJ Idea Database plugin (DataGrip) to query TimesTen database, but the fetching of the data takes extremely long.

```
-- 2023-05-23 13:39:09 [DB] [TimesTen] [console: console [TimesTen]] [session id: 1160215063] [statement id: 1756995763] finished - execution time: 1 s 746 ms, fetching time: 29 m 3 s 378 ms, total result sets count: 1
```

Comment: What JDBC driver do you use to get access to Oracle TimesTen?

Comment: Hi Vasilii, I am using C:\TimesTen\tt181_64\lib\ttjdbc11.jar, so it should be driver for TimesTen 18.1 and java 11.

Comment: Just for completeness Oracle DB works perfectly fine in the same version of IntelliJ ```[2023-06-22 12:09:40] 1 row retrieved starting from 1 in 339 ms (execution: 139 ms, fetching: 200 ms)```

Comment: It could be that the issue in JDBC driver itself. Is there any way to contact their support or file an issue?

Comment: The same driver works completely fine in SQL Developer.

Comment: So, if the driver works fine in IDEA it should work in DataGrip too. Could you share your IDEs versions and JBR versions?

Comment: I am using IntelliJ IDEA 2023.1.5 (Ultimate Edition) with DB plugin. My understanding is that it is the same as DataGrip.

Comment: Yes, you're absolutely right. IDEA with plugin is the same as DataGrip. So, do you use the same versions?

Answer (score 0):

DataGrip doesn't execute optimal queries for proper fetch in TimesTen database.

To stay up to date follow the issue [DBE-12832](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/DBE-12832/Slow-queries-in-datagrip-fast-normal-in-pgAdmin-other-GUI).